# Is there any way to disable var scoping?

Tags: meteor

The file-level JavaScript variable scoping introduced in Meteor 0.6.0
breaks projects and packages written in TypeScript (and CoffeeScript and probably
other transpilers). Is there any way to disable it?

For example, this Typescript code:

```
declare var Meteor: any;
module Model {
  export var Players = new Meteor.Collection('players');
}
```

Generates this JavaScript which no longer works because Model is no
longer considered global:

```
var Model;
(function (Model) {
    Model.Players = new Meteor.Collection('players');
})(Model || (Model = {}));
```

Prepending `this.Model = null;` is a workaround but it's redundant and you would have to apply it to all code used with Meteor (it's broken at least one of my Meteorite packages).

What was the reason for introducing Meteor specific JavaScript language semantics?

Comment: Related discussion on the Meteor GitHub: [Global app variables and 'use strict'](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1380)

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit nice his way because before having all these files sharing variables was a bit odd. Meteor treated every javascript file together as if they were one. Having larger projects (>20 js files) made it very difficult to modularize an application

I'm not too sure about typescript but it's suggested to use `@` to make something global before declaring it in coffeescript over at : http://docs.meteor.com/#coffeescript, perhaps there is something similar in typescript? (the `@` comes from coffeescript)

```
@myFunction = -> 123
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use one of the long established 
JavaScript idioms to implement modularity e.g. the revelation
pattern?

Enforcing peculiar non-JavaScript semantics is confusing for
developers and breaks existing code. It's an unusual and extreme
solution to a non-existent problem. If this feature is really
considered necessary it should be on an opt-in basis (maybe"use
meteor scoping" c.f. "use strict").

Comment: I also find this problematic for functions, see the discussion here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/meteor-talk/gYgYhv88nB4, basically with the server i'm fine with it because most stuff goes that way (node/express) but with client side js it breaks alot